# Creating `Uni` from a coroutine / suspending function

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

We are using quarkus to process messages this run on a regular function
in that we have to call a `suspend` function
basically

```kotlin
fun process (msg:Message):Message{
    val resFrom:Data = runBlocking{fetchDataFromDB(msg.key)}
    val processedMsg = processRoutingKey(msg,resFrom)
    return processedMsg

}
```

We would like to get the data as a `Uni` (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/creating-unis)
so basically we would like to get back

```kotlin
fun process (msg:Message){
    val resFrom:Uni<Data> = ConvertUni {fetchDataFromDB(msg.key)}
}
```

We need the uni further downstream one time to process some data but we would like to return a `Uni` from the method meaning

```kotlin
fun process (msg:Message):Uni<Message>{
    val resFrom:Uni<Data> = ConvertUni {fetchDataFromDB(msg.key)}
    val processed:Uni<Message> =process(msg,resfrom) 
    return processed 

}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code to the example to show how/where the `Uni` is supposed to be used? This may condition how you start the coroutine that is supposed to provide the `Uni`'s data, and it will show why you need a `Uni` in the first place. What is important in particular is how you control the lifetime of that coroutine.

Comment: @Joffrey I expanded a little more

Answer (score 1):

The signature `fun process(msg:Message): Uni<Message>` implies that some asynchronous mechanism needs to be started and will outlive the method call. It's like returning a `Future` or a `Deferred`. The function returns immediately but the underlying processing is not done yet.

In the coroutines world, this means you need to start a coroutine. However, like any async mechanism, it requires you to be conscious about where it will run, and for how long. This is defined by the `CoroutineScope` you use to start the coroutine, and this is why coroutine builders like `async` require such a scope.

So you need to pass a `CoroutineScope` to your function if you want it to start a coroutine that will last longer than the function call:

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.process(msg:Message): Uni<Message> {
    val uniResult = async { fetchDataFromDB(msg.key) }.asUni()
    return process(msg, uniResult) 
}
```

Here `Deferred<T>.asUni()` is provided by the library [mutiny-kotlin](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/kotlin). In the examples given in their doc, they use `GlobalScope` instead of asking the caller to pass a coroutine scope. This is usually a bad practice because it means you don't control the lifetime of the started coroutine, and you may leak things if you're not careful.

Accepting a `CoroutineScope` as receiver means the caller of the method can choose the scope of this coroutine, which will automatically cancel the coroutine when appropriate, and will also define the thread pool / event loop on which the coroutine runs.

Now, with that in mind, you see that you'll be using a mix of coroutines and `Uni` at the same level of API here, which is not great. I would advise to instead stick with suspend functions all the way, until you really have to convert to `Uni`.